# Create gradient map in sass

Tags: algorithm, sass, colors

I'm trying to generate a LCH gradient map with 2 gradients in SASS, where red-0 is super white red, red-1000 is super red, and red-2000 is super black red:

```scss
$colors: (
    red-0: #FCF5F5,
    red-100: #FFE2E2,
    red-200: #FFCFCD,
    red-300: #FFBCB8,
    red-400: #FFA9A3,
    red-500: #FF958C,
    red-600: #FF8175,
    red-700: #FF6C5E,
    red-800: #FF5545,
    red-900: #FF3A2B,
    red-1000: #FC0A0A,
    red-1100: #E60013,
    red-1200: #D00017,
    red-1300: #BA0019,
    red-1400: #A4001A,
    red-1500: #8F0019,
    red-1600: #790118,
    red-1700: #640316,
    red-1800: #500512,
    red-1900: #3C060C,
    red-2000: #2A0303
);
```

Is there a way to generate this with an algorithm?

Comment: Got as far as [this](https://gist.github.com/andrei-gheorghiu/8699f7a75fac9a38e8e5bd5d5dca6c66). But I don't know how to use `@for` inside a map. Second issue: `mix()` seems to generate different colors than yours. Are you sure about those values?

Comment: Here's an example of a dynamically generated map: https://github.com/vladimirlisovets/SASS-Color-Palettes/blob/master/colors.scss. Might help.